# WordPress kills an iframe's apostrophes

Tags: oembed, iframe

I'm using an iframe to let multiple sites embed one interactive element. On the iframe's [actual page](http://necir-bu.org/wp/interactives/sheriffinteract/interactive.html) it works fine, and it looks fine on another website I embedded it. But when I embed it in a WordPress blog, all my apostrophes show up as squares.

I tried removing all smart quotes and apostrophes with "dumb" quotes, no luck.

I tried replacing all the apostrophes with ' and, again, no luck

Any clues what my cause this?

The iframe code:

```
<iframe src="http://necir-bu.org/wp/interactives/sheriffinteract/interactive.html" name="interactive" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="5" align="center" vspace="5" widtha"590px" height="720px"></iframe>
```

And you can see the interactive code by just viewing the first link

Comment: Are you using the visual editor or the html editor?

Comment: html. Visual editor wipes it out completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apostrophs get translated in

```
&#39;
```

For the apostrophs, I guess it is an xss security feature. Check

settings > reading > encoding (UTF8)

But im not sure (maybe the theme sets another encoding fixed in the header instead of reading the global variable). In any case your embed show correct in my WP test post (so with an apostrophe).

Maybe you can set in the code of the iframe also

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of all the apostrophe problems, but the quotations and dashes are all stilled messed up. So weird.

Comment: can you give an example of a quotation and dash replacement in your iframe example that you put up?

Comment: Nope. I tried going back and adding them all in, and everything worked fine. I'm guessing there were some character encoding issues when I was pasting it in? I saved and copied everything using notepad to strip out smart/curly quotes, etc. Either way, it works now, and I can't thank you enough for the help.